# Why is my armor only upgradeable to level 4?

Tags: monster-hunter-world

I just started the game and am currently still in Low Rank, and I just finished the assigned quest "Into the Bowels of the Vale", where I had to hunt an Odogaron.

Once back to Astera, I went ahead and crafted myself the Odoragon Helmet, and a few other armor pieces to up my defense, but when I tried upgrading them, I noticed that I could only upgrade them up until level 4 which I thought was a bit low. This was also the case for the other armor pieces I crafted.

Though I noticed when I went over my old armor sets (now too weak), that I could upgrade them up until level 10, and when I went to the internet to look at the max level for armors, I saw that the Odogaron armor set has a max upgrade level of level 13, and could be augmented to level 23.

I know that augmentation is something that I will unlock once I finish the main game, but I am genuinely confused as to why I can't upgrade my armor past level 4? Am I going to unlock it further in the game?

P.S I still only have the base game, and I have yet to buy Icebourne,

Answer (score 2):

You'll unlock further levels as you progress in the game, specifically as you increase your Hunter Rank (HR).

Usually a higher rarity set (shown by the color) will have more defense than a lower rarity when they're both upgraded to your currently available max, regardless of the level number.

In the end, I believe the skills are more important than always being at the highest rarity armor, so consider what skills benefit your playstyle.

Comment: Do note: Lower rarity armor almost always winds up with more upgrade levels than higher rarity armor (even though it winds up with ultimately lower maximum values). This means "Level 17 Pukei-Pukei Armor" shouldn't be compared with "Level 13 Odogaron Armor", since a "Level 17" set does not mean it's inherently better than "Level 13" set (compare the total defense scores, instead!).

Comment: Exactly! That's what I was trying to convey with my 2nd paragraph, but I think Raven Dreamer's phrasing is more clear